# How to swap places by string value in array?

Tags: javascript

Need to swap / sort indexes in an array of strings.

This is array of languages:

```
LANGUAGES = ['en', 'de', 'fr'];
```

This is the `const` which contains `native_languge` value. N

```
const native_languge = 'de';
```

native_languge is changed dynamically, that means sometimes value is different. Like `en` or `fr`

Need to sort `LANGUAGES` by `native_languge` value.

How to sort this array of strings by dynamically `native_language` ('de', 'fr', 'en')?

Comment: Why `['de', 'fr', 'en']`? Why not `['de', 'en', 'fr']`?

Comment: The order doesnt matter as long as the native language's is first in the array @GerardoFurtado

Comment: if `native_language` is `const` it should not change. You will therefor not need to sort it.

Comment: @Kevin.a I'm on S.O. long enough to know that we should never suppose what OP wants, no matter how logical it seems to be.

Comment: @fredrik `const` cannot be reassigned. It can be changed/mutated

Comment: nativate_language coming from as part of response from the server. It's changed based on the chosen language.

Comment: Thank you all on efforts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take the delta of the check with the default language.

```js
var LANGUAGES = ['en', 'de', 'fr'],
    native_language = 'de';
    
LANGUAGES.sort((a, b) => (b === native_language) - (a === native_language));

console.log(LANGUAGES);
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom sorting function:

```
const sortByLang = lang => (a, b) => a === lang ? -1 : 1
```

and use it to sort in place:

```
const LANGUAGES = ['en', 'de', 'fr'];
const native_language = 'fr';

LANGUAGES.sort(sortByLang(native_language))

// ["fr", "en", "de"]
```